# Create an Apple Homekit accessory with NodeMCU (ESP8266)

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, homekit

My goal is to create a simple LED controlled by my iPhone through Homekit.
I'd like to do it using only a NodeMCU (ESP8266).

I found lots of solutions using a NodeJS library ([HAP-NodeJS](https://github.com/KhaosT/HAP-NodeJS)), which works well on my PC, but obviously can't run on a NodeMCU board.

As I understand, all these solutions require a RaspberryPI (or similar board running Linux) that talks with the NodeMCU board. But I don't like this solution.

Is there a way to achieve this goal only with a NodeMCU board?

---

**Update 1** (25/01/2017)

Ok, I'm reading lots of blogs and watching some videos, and I'm understanding more about this topic.

I found [NodeMCU Flasher](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-flasher) to install the firmware on the board, and I found the [firmware](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware) I'd like to use (I think I could be more comfortable with Lua).

First problem... I'm using a Mac, and NodeMCU Flasher is for Windows... Is there an alternative?

I downloaded also [ESPlorer](https://esp8266.ru/esplorer/). Does it provide the same functionality as NodeMCU Flasher?

Comment: What firmware do you use? NodeMCU, Arduino, MicroPython, ...

Comment: I'm still a newbie of this king of programming. So, I'm not sure what firmware I'm using right now. Probably Arduino.

Comment: Anyway, if some solution require a specific firmware, I can change it.

Comment: run the espEasy firmware, or use the arduino ide which is cross-platform and very well supported, and checkout the example mqtt sketches, which should be enough to get you going. fwiw, if you're new stick to arduino over lua; you'll find 10x as many sketches, videos, and online info.

Comment: Thanks dandavis, I'm going to check this espEasy!

Comment: I think we are going a lil bit out of topic. The initial question was "is there a way to communicate with Apple Homekit directly from the ESP board?" Something like a library. Or I need a RaspberryPI (or similar) to run a NodeJS server with HAP-NodeJS like in all the articles I read.

Comment: @RikyTres asking for libraries on SO is off-topic.

Comment: @gre_gor we are talking about programming a board to be able to communicate with a specific Apple protocol. I think libraries is fully on topic.

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/espressif/esptool it should fit your needs

Answer (score 1):

Please check [this](https://github.com/HomeACcessoryKid/ESP8266-HomeKit).

Public Apple's HomeKit protocol code has been around for some time for more potent processors (notably HAP-NodeJS). This is a rewrite for the ESP8266 to make the server foundation. This project uses ESP8266_RTOS_SDK and WolfCrypt 3.9.8 for the crypto. It will however NOT deliver a certified HomeKit device.